# Page Layout FindControl

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I am generating dynamic webcontrols in Sharepoint 2010 page layout depending upon the attribute.

```
private void generatefield(SPContext newContext, int litem,Guid listId, SPField field,string displayid, string isHidden, string isEdit)

{

TableRow row = new TableRow();
   TableCell cellLabel = new TableCell();
   cellLabel.Text = string.Format("<strong>{0}</strong>", field.Title);
   row.Cells.Add(cellLabel);
   Metadata.Rows.Add(row);
   if (field.Title != null)
   {
       BaseFieldControl webcontrol = field.FieldRenderingControl;
       webcontrol.ID = string.Format("ctrl_{0}", field.InternalName);
       webcontrol.FieldName = field.Title;
       webcontrol.ItemContext = newContext;
       webcontrol.RenderContext = newContext;
       if (field is SPFieldCalculated || isEdit == "false")
       {
           webcontrol.ControlMode = SPControlMode.Display;
       }
       else
       {
           webcontrol.ControlMode = SPControlMode.Edit;

       }
       webcontrol.ListId = listId;
       webcontrol.ItemId = litem;
       cellLabel = new TableCell();
       cellLabel.Text = string.Format("<strong>{0}</strong>", field.Title);
       cellLabel.Controls.Add(webcontrol);
       row.Cells.Add(cellLabel);
       Metadata.Rows.Add(row);

   }
}
```

This generates Controls perfectly no problem. When the user enters the data and click the button save i am trying to find control and get the value like this

```
protected void save_click(Object sender,
                            EventArgs e)
     {

         for (int j = 0; j <= SAVE_Columns.Length; j++)
         {
             string columnvalue = SAVE_Columns[j].ToString();
            Control ctrl = Page.Master.FindControl(SAVE_Columns[j]);
            ContentPlaceHolder placeholdermain = Page.Master.FindControl("PlaceHolderMain") as ContentPlaceHolder;
            Control ctrl1 = placeholdermain.FindControl(columnvalue);
             string columnname = SAVE_Columns[j].ToString();
            string ctrlValue = getControlValue(ctrl);
            using (SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web)
            {
                try
                {

                    SPList list = web.Lists["Invoices"];

                    string invoiceno = Page.Request.QueryString.Get("invoicenumber");

                    SPQuery query = new SPQuery();

                    int invoicenumber = Convert.ToInt32(invoiceno);

                    query.Query = "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name=\"SupplierDocumentNumber\" /><Value Type=\"Text\">" + invoiceno + "</Value></Eq></Where>";

                    SPListItemCollection listitem = list.GetItems(query);

                    foreach (SPListItem litem in listitem)
                    {
                        litem[columnname] = ctrlValue;
                        litem.Update();
                    }

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                }
            }
         }

     }
```

The SAVE_Columns[] is an array which have the field internalname of the field which are generated in Page layout.

The Problem the Find Control always giving me null. As you noticed the I have tried Page.FindControl, This.Findcontrol .. Nothing is working.

This is the generateValue function to get the value from the control is like this

```
 public string getControlValue(Control SPCtrl)
     {


         if (SPCtrl is TextField)
         {

             return ((TextField)SPCtrl).Text;

         }

         if (SPCtrl is CheckBoxChoiceField)
         {

             return ((CheckBoxChoiceField)SPCtrl).Value.ToString();

         }

         if (SPCtrl is NumberField)
         {

             return ((NumberField)SPCtrl).Text;

         }

         if (SPCtrl is RadioButtonChoiceField)
         {

             return ((RadioButtonChoiceField)SPCtrl).Value.ToString();

         }

         if (SPCtrl is RichTextField)
         {

             return ((RichTextField)SPCtrl).Text;

         }

         if (SPCtrl is BooleanField)
         {

             return ((BooleanField)SPCtrl).Value.ToString();

         }

         if (SPCtrl is DropDownChoiceField)
         {

             return ((DropDownChoiceField)SPCtrl).Value.ToString();

         }

         if (SPCtrl is DateTimeField)
         {

             if (((DateTimeField)SPCtrl).Value == null)
             {

                 return "NullDateTime";
             }
             else
             {
                 return ((DateTimeField)SPCtrl).Value.ToString();
             }

         }
         return "";

     }
```

How to retrieve the value from the control

Comment: If you debug it, is there a value assigned to "ctrl"?

Comment: your control is probably not in the master page directly but down in one or more child levels. if you are having trouble you can try a recursive approach http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2006/Apr/09/ASPNET-20-MasterPages-and-FindControl

Comment: Hi Joanne, If i debug iam getting null value..

Comment: And does placeholdermain get assigned to? As Tiago says, the control you're trying to reach is probably inside something else that you need to get first. Is Save_columns inside PlaceHolderMain?

Comment: placeholdermain is getting assigned with the placeholder but if i use placeholdermain.Findcontrol it's always giving null. The Save_columns is an array where the name of the control is stored on page load event.

Answer (score 0):

This is how inside my Placeholdermain Contentholder have the content. In this i want for the Input field.

Forexample here my Textbox id is not InvoiceTaxAmount instead it is ctl00$PlaceHolderMain$ctrl_InvoiceTaxAmountPos$ctl00$TextField . If i use ClientID for searching iam getting Object reference not set to instance error

**Steuerbetrag**0,00
    
        **Steuerbetrag Positionen**
        
    
    
        **Leistungsdatum**
        g_strDateTimeControlIDs["SPInvoiceDateOfActivity"] = "ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_ctrl_InvoiceDateOfActivity_ctl00_DateTimeField_DateTimeFieldDate";
        
        
        Leistungsdatum Datum

```
</span></td>
</tr><tr>
    <td><strong>Abteilung</strong></td><td><span dir="none"><span id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_ctrl_InvoiceDepartment_ctl00"><input name="ctl00$PlaceHolderMain$ctrl_InvoiceDepartment$ctl01" type="hidden" id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_ctrl_InvoiceDepartment_ctl01" class="ms-taxonomy ms-taxonomy-height ms-long" /><DIV id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_ctrl_InvoiceDepartment_ctl02" class="ms-taxonomy ms-taxonomy-height ms-long"></DIV></span></span></td>
</tr><tr>
    <td><strong>Bestellbezug</strong></td><td><span dir="none">
    <input name="ctl00$PlaceHolderMain$ctrl_InvoiceOrderExists$ctl00$TextField" type="text" maxlength="255" id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_ctrl_InvoiceOrderExists_ctl00_TextField" title="Bestellbezug" class="ms-long ms-spellcheck-true" /><br />
</span></td>
</tr>
```

```
   </td>
   <td width="50%" align="right">
   <table id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_Metadataright" border="0">
```

Comment: Output your SAVE_columns array contents to string and copy them here, see what that produces.

Comment: SAVE_COLUMNS[0]="InvoiceTaxAmount",SAVE_COLUMNS[1]="InvoiceTaxAmount", SAVE_COLUMNS[2]="InvoiceDateOfActivity" and so on..

Comment: If you call the .Parent method on those columns, what container does it say they're in?

Comment: I think my controls are lost in Postback of the Button click maybe that's it is always giving me Null. The FindControl can find the ASP:Button or ASP:TextBox which is created in the page itself(Static not Dynamically). how can i get the controls back in the save button onclick event ?.

Comment: Are you building the controls in Page_Load?

Comment: Yes iam building it Page_load